# Meteor: Can't run server

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Need your help :)

Meteor is installed without any errors and warnings. Created new demo app (from Meteor examples). But each time I'm trying to run it I get:

```
/root/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                                                throw(ex);
                                                      ^
Error: spawn ENOMEM
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:927:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:715:9)
    at /root/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/tools/mongo_runner.js:208:32
```

How can I fix that? Whats wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ENOMEM` means [you're running out of memory](http://swordfish1987.wordpress.com/2009/04/09/enomem-error/). Close other running apps?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then maybe you know how much memory Meteor needs to start? I'm trying to understand this on very cheap VDS where I can get more memory but for more money.

Comment: Had to upgrade my VDS plan and now everything is Ok. Thank you ;)